# Non-Jews in messianic times

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, messiah

I have once heard that when the Mashiach comes the non-Jews will be like Jews and the Jews like angels.

Don't know where the source might be.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This maamar (chapter V) says non-Jews will have a spiritual descent: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2299272/jewish/Maamar-Beela-HaMaves-LaNetzach.htm